# Web Push notifications with iOS 11.3

Tags: ios, ios11, progressive-web-apps, onesignal

EDIT - MARCH 2023
ITS HERE iOS With 16.4

---

With the release of iOS 11.3 and it's inclusion of service workers, I have been trying to find information about whether or not web push is also available now, particularly for the usage in PWA's.

Does anyone have any knowledge on this or know where I can find the information.

I Currently use Onesignal for my push notification package and it works very very well for browser and Android. So here is hoping that if it is supported now, they get it up and running fast.

Comment: WebPush is not available currently still.

There seems to be very little information if any, available on any timelines also.

Comment: We're up to 11.4 now and still no change.

Comment: 12.1 still no web push

Comment: 13, still no web push

Comment: 14, and still no webpush

Comment: ios 15, no webpush

Comment: ios 16.....ITS FINALY COMING  https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-16-preview/features/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, in iOS 16.4, Web Push is available to web apps after being added to the home screen.

Its finally here. https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT213407

Answer (score 61):

Bad news : Apple has included services worker but not Push API so you can't receive push notification.

https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7

I'm really disappointed...

### EDIT - SEPTEMBER 2019

No improvement about Push notifications on iOS 13.1

### EDIT - OCTOBER 2019

You can sign this petition opened by WonderPush.

https://www.change.org/p/tim-cook-apple-inc-implement-web-push-notifications-on-ios-devices

### EDIT - MARCH 2020

No improvement about Push notifications on iOS 14

### EDIT - SEPTEMBER 2021

No improvement about Push notifications on iOS 15

### EDIT - MARCH 2023

ITS HERE iOS With 16.4

Comment: How does this not answer the question? He asked if web push is available in iOS 11.3, and this answer was clear, accurate, and included a source.

Comment: -->    Fkc Apple    <--

Answer (score 2):

Good news -- Apple finally [announced](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-16-preview/features/) that Web Push for iOS is coming in 2023!

> Web push notifications: Adds support for opt‑in notifications on iOS.
> Coming in 2023.

Since this question is tagged with OneSignal, OneSignal has announced that they will also support iOS Web Push once Apple makes it available.

Comment: finally, we have it coming

Answer (score 0):

I am following the roadmap of the webkit and it seems they are working on it:

https://webkit.org/status/#?search=manifest

Hopefully by end of the year, It will be released in production.

Comment: How is the feature "manifest" relevant to Web Push Notifications??? I don't think it is related is it?

Comment: manifest is used along with the service workers, which are tied in with web push.