# PWA: safari web push notifications

Tags: push-notification, safari, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Does Safari 12.1 support service workers PWA push notifications?
I tried this [demo](https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload_demo.html) on iOS but it still does not work for me.

Is there any chance to get them?
Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, the iOS 12 does not support offline feature of some PWAs. Check [this post](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=192166).

Comment: thank you, will follow!

Answer (score 6):

There is no communication about this feature at this moment... Apple doesn't support Push API.

[Web Push notifications with iOS 11.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575679/web-push-notifications-with-ios-11-3)