# PWA Web Push Notification in IOS

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, firebase, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a PWA. I want it to be suitable for both android and IOS user. But I see some articles saying that web push notification is not available for IOS.

My question is:

1. Is it still unavailable now?
2. If unavailable, what can I do to achieve this?

I'm seeking suggestion about these. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575679/web-push-notifications-with-ios-11-3/49576525#49576525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://caniuse.com/push-api it is only available via Apple’s custom protocol: Safari Push Notifications. This however requires an Apple App Id. Another solution would be to fall back on email/text message, or integrate with a notification app like https://pushover.net/

Comment: Can I use Firebase Cloud Messaging for this?

Comment: I am afraid not. Only if you build an app distributed via the App Store, and then it also requires an App Id from Apple. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client States it only works for websites if the browser supports Push API, which is not the case on iOS.

Comment: So, in conclusion, I can't have PWA web push notification on IOS, right?

Comment: Only with Apple’s custom implementation which requires an App Id: https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/

Comment: Safari push notifications are desktop only.

Comment: as of march 2023 its now avalaible with ios too
https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT213407